# 'AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using Audiotoolbox

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)buttonPressedWithSound:(id)sender;

@end
```

and in the .m file

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressedWithSound:(id)sender {

int randomSoundNumber = arc4random() % 4; //random number from 0 to 3

NSLog(@"random NR = %i", randomSoundNumber);

NSString *effectTitle;

switch (randomSoundNumber) {
    case 0:
        effectTitle = @"Come at me BRO!";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

SystemSoundID soundID;

NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:effectTitle ofType:@"mp3"];
NSSound *sound = [[[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: soundPath byReference: NO]       autorelease];

[sound play];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(soundUrl), &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

but when i went to run in on my iphone it came up in the log that in the AUGraph.h with     #include AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h and 'AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h' file not found to the right of it.

How can i fix this to run it on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

As stackmonster said make sure its in the Build Phases>Link Binary with Library
you also need to #include it in the class you are trying to use it in (maybe try to include audioUnit as well but dont see why you would have too)

you can also try to use AVAudioPlayer, which might be easier for you (i know it was for me)

```
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:NULL];

theAudio.volume = 1.0;

theAudio.delegate = self;

[theAudio prepareToPlay];

[theAudio play];
```

Comment: so i put this in the .m file, what about the .h file?

Comment: what was the fix?  AVAudioPlayer or one of the imports?  Glad it helped regardless of which it was though

Comment: well it was fix but now when i put in your code in the .m file errors poped up like unknown type name, is the something that goes in the .h file?

Answer (score -1):

Add the audiotoolbox framework to your app in Build Phases...linked libraries